# How do you create a user defined formula functions in R

Tags: r, syntax, formula, user-defined-functions

R has the ability to allow you to defined a formula with a transformation function applied to one of the variables. For example in the following formula, the logarithmic transformation will be applied to variable `b`.

```
y ~ a + log(b) + c
```

**How does one define their own formula functions in R without the use of `I()`?** For example applying the user defined function `foo` to `a` in the following formula.

```
y ~ foo(a) + b
```

Comment: it's similar to defining a normal function and calling it, i believe

Comment: `func <- function(x)  x ; form <- as.formula("mpg~func(cyl)+am" ) ; lm(form, data = mtcars)`  OR  ` lm(mpg ~ func(cyl) + am)`

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use your own functions in R formulas.

An example function:

```
foo <- function(x)
  log(x) ^ 2
```

Data:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(y = rnorm(5), x = rgamma(5, 2))
```

Create model matrix based on formula and data:

```
mod <- model.matrix(y ~ 1 + foo(x), data = dat)
mod
#   (Intercept)     foo(x)
# 1           1 0.16837521
# 2           1 0.02222275
# 3           1 0.68509896
# 4           1 0.01936180
# 5           1 0.14758002
# attr(,"assign")
# [1] 0 1
```

The function is indeed applied to the data:

```
identical(foo(dat$x), unname(mod[ , "foo(x)"]))
# [1] TRUE
```